# Ubuntu/Arch Linux command to create multiple Linux USB installer

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, iso

How is the Linux Ubuntu/Arch command to create multiple Linux USB installer, at least 3, in a single USB disk ?
Or has there been AIO boot tool/utilty in linux just like such of Windows ?

Comment: I find it inconvenient to keep a multiboot USB drive up to date. Instead I download (often via torrent) current iso files and store them in my main computer. When I want to use one distro or version, I create a USB boot drive from its iso file. So I see USB drives as temporary devices - I write / rewrite / overwrite new systems onto them all the time.

Answer (score 1):

[Ventoy](https://github.com/ventoy/Ventoy) is one I found recently from a Hackernews article; it lets you literally stick the raw .iso image straight onto the USB drive and boot from that. Obviously can then put multiple of them on it too. You just have to run their installer script first on the drive to make it a "Ventoy install USB".

Others: [MultiBootUSB](http://multibootusb.org/) seems to be the classic, but from the comments in [this article,](https://itsfoss.com/multiple-linux-one-usb/) it looks like that's much older and not being maintained anymore. Haven't used it personally but I'm pretty sure there's no way to use single .iso's like with Ventoy. BTW that comment section might be good for scoping out what alternatives are popular nowadays, if you still need other options.